# Java: NullPointerException with substrings

Tags: java, exception

I'm having a problem in one of my methods. Please keep in mind that I am learning Java in college so I might not be up to speed on simple things. Below is a method that is made to add expressions. The problems I'm running into is found where `x = x.substring.(1, x.length() - 1);` I'm getting an exception that reads:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I have no idea what that means and/or how to fix it. If you could point me in the right direction, that'd be great.
Thanks.

```
public static int adder(String x){
    int total = 0;
    x = x.substring(1, x.length() - 1);
    sopln(x);
    String[] nums = x.split("\\+");
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i){
        if(nums[i].charAt(0) == ' ' || nums[i].charAt(nums[i].length()-1) == ' '){
            sopln("ERROR: Excess whitespace identified.");
            nums[i] = nums[i].trim();
        }
        nums[i] = nums[i].replaceAll(" ", "");
        if(nums[i].charAt(0) == '-')
            total -= Integer.parseInt(nums[i]);

        else
            total += Integer.parseInt(nums[i]);
    }
    return total;

}
```

Comment: The error message will give you a line number. Go to that line. Look at that code. Think about why that variable is null.

Comment: since the error occurs at `x=x.substring.(1,x.length() - 1);` it should be `x` that is `null`... `x` is passed as an argument, so how are you calling `adder`???

Comment: If adder is called with null or adder("") it will throw an error at that line.

Comment: I think it would be a problem if your `String` was equal to "", because you start at 1 for the substring, and go until .length() -1, which would equal -1.

Comment: what was the value of x when you had this exception?

Answer (score 0):

> The problems I'm running into is found where `x=x.substring.(1,x.length() - 1);`

This means that at some point you are calling `adder` with an argument that is `null`.  That's the only way you can get an NPE at that point.

Find out where and why the argument is null, and then fix it.

(It could be an explicit `null`, but it is more likely to be coming from an uninitialized field, or from some method that returns a `null` to indicate something; e.g. `BufferedReader.readLine()` returns `null` when the reader reached the EOF position.)

Answer (score 0):

It probably means that your String x is null and not actually set to an Object of a String.

How are you calling the method?

Does it happen when you call it with a hard coded string like

```
int num = adder("string checking in");
```

if not, then somewhere upstream in your code, that String variable you are passing into the adder method is null.

Comment: I have no idea how to format my comments but: I'm calling adder in a for loop where I'm saying, "int total = adder(string[i]).

Comment: and you are sure that string[i] is actually set to a String?

Answer (score 0):

you are passing a null value when you call adder(the_string), where the_string is null